# XQuery OSB Transforming String to shortDate

Tags: xml, xquery, osb

I need to convert String to the date on one of the xml nodes 
which has the following xsd:

```
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="executionDate" type="general:ShortDate"/>
```

my String is in format yyyymmdd  i need to convert it to ddmmyyyy shortDate format.

I'm using OSB and try to do it the following way:

```
{xs:dateTime(xs:date('20041212'))}
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
<con:reason xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/context">OSB Insert action failed updating variable "body": {err}XP0021: "20041212": can not cast to {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}date: error: date: Invalid date value: wrong type: 20041212</con:reason>
```

Can anybody just help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XQuery, a date is represented by the ISO format: yyyy-mm-dd.  To make your query compile, you want to convert this to:

```
{xs:dateTime(xs:date('2004-12-12'))}
```

but then the result is

```
2004-12-12T00:00:00
```

which I don't think you are looking for.

Can you not just do this?

```
concat(substring($date, 7, 2), substring($date, 5, 2), substring($date, 1, 4))
```